# Multiple irregular hit areas on bitmap

Tags: android, layout, bitmap

I'm working on a app that has a bitmap image of a map on the homescreen. When the user clicks any of the areas, it takes them to a certain section. I tried looking for something simliar, and I couldn't figure it out.

I suppose one solution would be to make a view for each piece in a FrameLayout, but that seemed like a bad idea.

I hacked together a poor solution that samples a color map based on the users click, but the sampling is never accurate.

[image: Here is the image of the map]

Thoughts?

Comment: If it helps your search, what you want is known as an "[image map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map)", at least in HTML, where it's probably most well-known. A quick Google finds a few likely Android imagemap implementations, like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/socratica-android/source/browse/trunk/socratica-android/src/com/socratica/mobile/ImageMap.java?spec=svn6&r=6) or [this one](https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap).

Comment: One other thing that springs to mind -- did you consider having the nice rectangular labels of the areas work as simple buttons? Might be a lot easier, and perhaps just as intuitive to a user, as long as they look obviously button-like.

Comment: Oh! I just didn't know what it was called. I tried hitmap, hitarea... anyways. Thanks!